# Bootstrap Modal to appear as error message

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have this modal that contains a form and as soon as it hits submit button, another modal should appear as a success message or an error message.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="events" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#0A0A1E">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><font color="white">x</font></a>
                    <h4><font color="white">ADD EVENT</font></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">






                        <form id ="massform" method="POST" role="form" action="SAeventUpdate.php">

                        <div class="form-group">

                          <label>MASS TYPE</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <input class='form-control' list = 'title' required name='title' placeholder= 'Please specify if mass type is unavailable'>
                              <datalist id='title'>
                                <option class= 'titl' value="Baptism">Baptism</option>
                                <option class= 'titl' value="Confirmation">Confirmation</option>
                                <option class= 'titl' value="Requiem">Requiem</option>
                                <option class= 'titl' value="Marriage">Marriage</option>
                              </datalist>
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-bullhorn"></span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>LANGUAGE</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <select class='form-control' required name='language' placeholder= 'Please select language'>

                                <option  value="Cebuano">Cebuano</option>
                                <option  value="English">English</option>
                              </select>
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-comment-o"></span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Add Event</button>
                        </form>
                 </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The form then sends the information to a php file and undergo a condition and and an error message should appear through a modal without closing the previous modal if the action is not possible.
Is this even possible? :)

Comment: for better UX, I would just put error/success message on top of modal body, another modal is just confusing

Comment: how do you put a message on top of the modal body?

Comment: just insert it with jquery before form .. you can create whole new div with jquery based on ajax response (from your submit..)